# AMD Graphics Card missing after reformat

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card

I own a laptop that used to have a Hard Drive, so one day I decided to replace the Hard Drive with an SSD, upon doing that and reformating my laptop AMD Graphics Card went missing and I was unable to locate it in the Device Manager. I tried to check in my BIOS but was unable to navigate around. I also tried downloading the latest drivers for the AMD Graphics Card but nothing happened. My laptop is also updated to the latest version of Windows. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. Laptop Details:

Laptop: TOSHIBA Satellite S50t-B

CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-4510U

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (x64 bit)

Supposed to be AMD Card: 2Gb AMD Radeon™ R7 M260 Graphics

Comment: What do you mean by "*I tried to check in my BIOS but was unable to navigate around*" exactly? Have a look here for all Toshiba drivers, firmware updates, apps, etc. Perhaps you are missing something available here so look thru the list and consider BIOS updates here as well --> https://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200012818&osId=26

Comment: Lastly, this might be the direct AMD R7 Series driver package you need for Windows 10 x64 right from AMD: https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-r7-series/amd-radeon-r7-200-series/amd-radeon-r7-m260. Simply uninstall all AMD Graphics package from your machine if applicable, reboot it, and then install that, reboot, and now check to see if back to normal.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT your comments were pretty good but after doing one of the answers below I noticed that the error could be a hardware error, so I checked it out and now it works again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the following procedure:
If you still have the previous HDD, boot with it and see if the GPU still functions.

If the GPU still does not function, then it's simply broken or while manipulating
the hardware you have undone some contact. Maybe the GPU just needs to be
reseated.

If the GPU functions well, then this might be a driver problem:
Export the AMD driver in that installation, restore the SSD and reboot,
then install that driver on the SSD.

For driver tools, see this list of
[free driver software](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your chipset drivers. That's often the issue when hardware is not recognized.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the missing graphics card drivers through Windows update by:

1. Clicking the start menu on your taskbar or pressing the Windows key on your keyboard.
2. Typing 'Check for Updates' on your keyboard, then select the Check for Updates option with a cycling icon as its prefix.
3. Clicking the 'Check for updates' button.
4. Wait for Windows to complete the update.

If this doesn't work, you can always search your laptop's specific model, in this case, the TOSHIBA Satellite S50t-B, and adding in video drivers at the end. It should take you to your manufacturer's support website where they may provide software for your laptop's hardware.

Comment: My laptop is fully updated, has the latest software for my laptop, and has the latest drivers for AMD. Thank you for the help anyways.